# Proving that the $[g,x]^n=e$ if $G$ is nilpotent of degree $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, self-learning

This is an article from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_group#Explanation_of_term) which I saw wondering as to how to prove it.

The question is If $G$ is nilpotent of degree $n$ then $[g,x]^n=e$ for all $x \in G$, where $[g,x]=g^{-1}x^{-1}gx$.

I am only aware of the definition that $G$ is nilpotent if $Z_c(G)=G$. I have no idea as to how to prove this. I someone can give any hints it would be great.

Comment: This is not what is said on that page. What is said is that $\underbrace{[g, [g, [\ldots}_{n\ \text{times}}, x ]\ldots]] = e$.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) for the meaning of "nth iteration".

Comment: Also, your definition of a nilpotent group looks suspicious. What is $Z_C(G)$?

Comment: @DanShved, apparently (?) the OP meant that the upper central series reaches $\;G\;$ after a finite number $\;c\;$ of steps...It surprises me the OP didn't mention the lower central series...

Comment: @DonAntonio Ah, so it probably lacks the "for some integer $c$" addendum. Looks plausible. Thanks, I didn't see it.

Comment: @Dan Shved thanks a lot I am reading from Abstract Algebra by Dummit and Foote He mentions the upper central series first and latter on tells about the lower central series.